# bash script rename input file while copying

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, rename

I am running my bash script with a file as the input file:

> ./myscript.sh anyfilename.txt

and then here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file=$1
dest_dir="./destination"
mkdir -p "$dest_dir"
cp "$input_file" "$dest_dir"
```

when I run it, it copies the file to the **destination** directory using the same name as it is passed to the bash parameter, **anyfilename.txt**.

### Question:

how can I copy the input file into the destination directory by renaming it always as **myfile.txt**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command like:

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file=$1
new_file=$2
dest_dir="./destination"
mkdir -p "$dest_dir"
cp "$input_file" "${dest_dir}/${new_file}"
```

and run the script like:

```
./myscript.sh anyfilename.txt myfile.txt
```